# Aggregating a raster with an input in R

Tags: r, shiny, aggregate, raster, r-raster

How does one dynamically aggregate a raster in Shiny?

i.e. using an example .flt file:
https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO2/ETOPO2v2-2006/ETOPO2v2c/raw_binary/

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("shiny")
library("raster")

ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
            plotOutput("canvasHere")
    ),

      sliderInput("sliderRes", label = h5("Resolution reduction"),
        min = 1, max = 100, value = 5)      

) ## UI end

shinyServer <- function(input, output) {

    BMgradient <- raster("/home/berg/Downloads/ETOPO2v2c_f4_LSB/ETOPO2v2c_f4_LSB.flt",crs=NA,template=NULL)

    ##resolutionFactor <- input$sliderRes
    resolutionFactor <- 5

    BMgradient <- aggregate(BMgradient, fact=resolutionFactor, fun=max)

    p <- rasterToPoints(BMgradient)
    bmdf <- data.frame(p)
    colnames(bmdf) <- c("bbb", "ccc", "varFillBBB")

    output$canvasHere <- renderPlot({
        ggplot()+
            geom_tile(data=bmdf,aes(bbb,ccc,fill=varFillBBB)) 

    })
}

print("Processed code")

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = shinyServer))
```

Now, usually I'd just adjust a variable in the server by using:

`resolutionFactor <- input$sliderRes`

However, this doesn't seem to work for raster aggregation, and I just have to use a static resolution factor such as: `resolutionFactor <- 5`

How can I do this dynamically via a slider in the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I managed to find the solution.

The raster aggregation itself needs to be placed in the  reactive environment.
i.e.

```
output$yourOutput <- renderPlot({

BMgradient <- raster(...)
resolutionFactor <- input$sliderRes

## Rest of raster code

ggplot()+
        geom_tile(data=bmdf,aes(bbb,ccc,fill=varFillBBB))
})
```

Then, you can manually adjust the slider and the raster will dynamically aggregate.